# Elink function returns HTTP 414 issue

Tags: python, biopython

I am searching for terms in pubmed and finding the respective ids in pubmed central. This is my code

```
Entrez.email = "Afsrtfgdsfg@bobxx.com"
batch_size = 10000

def idconv(idkeys):
    handle = Entrez.elink(db='pmc', dbfrom='pubmed', id=idkeys)
    return [each['LinkSetDb'][0]['Link'][0]['Id'] for each in Entrez.read(handle)]

def search(Term):
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pubmed', term=Term, retmax=100000000)
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    idlist = record["IdList"]
    return idlist

mylist = search('"bacterial infections and mycoses"[MeSH Terms] AND pmc cc license[filter]AND ("review"[Publication Type]) AND "journal article"[Publication Type] NOT "letter"[Publication Type] NOT "comment"[Publication Type]')
print(len(idconv(mylist)))
```

I always get the error.

```
HTTP Error 414: Request-URI Too Large
```

How might I fix this issue?

Comment: You can't. It's not in your hands: your search term (more specifically, the URL you're sending) is too massive according to the web server. You could try a much smaller search term, and filter results afterwards.

Comment: Here's a [relevant search result](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.bio.general/8696) for people who've encountered this problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used chunks of 600 at a time and got the result

```
from Bio import Entrez

Entrez.email = "Afsrtfgdsfg@bobxx.com"
batch_size = 10000
#['LinkSetDb'][0]['Link'][0]['Id']
def idconv(idkeys):
    res=[]
    for i in range(0, len(idkeys), 600):
        handle = Entrez.elink(db='pmc', dbfrom='pubmed', id=idkeys[i:i+600])
        for each in Entrez.read(handle):
            try:
                res.append(each['LinkSetDb'][0]['Link'][0]['Id'])
            except IndexError:
                pass
    return res

def search(Term):
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pubmed', term=Term, retmax=100000000)
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    idlist = record["IdList"]
    return idlist

mylist = search('"bacterial infections and mycoses"[MeSH Terms] AND pmc cc license[filter]AND ("review"[Publication Type]) AND "journal article"[Publication Type] NOT "letter"[Publication Type] NOT "comment"[Publication Type]')
print(len(mylist))
print (len(idconv(mylist)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Biopython 1.67 (due shortly) should fix this by switching to using HTTP POST when a very long HTTP GET URL would be needed. See:

https://github.com/biopython/biopython/commit/674da1122593cdc492c3ae480c7c1b7db06343b7

In the meantime, you could try installing Biopython from source?